# Change Market name

Tags: android, console, rename, google-play

I'm new to publishing Android apps. Our app's name and the string that users should search for to find it on the Market is `Eksjö`

When I first uploaded it, the upload form suggested the name Eksjo (the name of the project, since Eclipse/Android SDK disallows deviant characters in the project name). Sadly, I accepted this and noticed it could be found (since the word is unique and is in the description, presumably), but that the Market name was `Eksjo`.

I edited the upload form, only changing the App name to Eksjö, but this did not change the Market name. **Perhaps I was impatient, and an hour or so later it would have changed?**

Anyway, I went back to Eclipse to change the :label (which I've since learned has nothing to do with the Market name), but it was already set correctly.

The best thread I've found on the subject is this: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b1a6ad78ce584a40#

**I've come up with 3 ideas so far:**

1. It says that the app Title can only be set from the Developer Console, but I can't type anything in the Console tab containing the console messages. (Am I barking up the wrong tree? Intuitively, I would think that typing setTitle('Eksjö') would only change the title of the current or possibly the main view of the app at runtime?)
2. The other alternative would be to upload an upgrade, where basically nothing has changed but where I can hopefully type a new Market name in the upload form. The question is whether this changes anything at all.
3. The third alternative would be to upload a completely new identical app, but with the correct Market name. But to do that, I'd have to change the package names (and sub-names, ie. com.whatever.common, com.whatever.viewname1, etc.) Can I do that with a refactor or do I have to manually rename all the views and includes?

Which one is the ticket, 1, 2, or 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think 1 is your answer. and this can occour by changing the default string appName in your strings.xml file to the one you want. Also changing the market name and icon takes some time so just wait for the data to populate.

Comment: I unpublished the first version after the Market name change in the web form didn't "take". Since the app_name string was already correct in this version, could I just publish it again? I'm hesitant only because if someone downloads it, I read that not editable anymore.

Comment: It worked instantly this time. Perhaps it needed to be unpublished (for a short while?) and then the title changes instantly, as opposed to just changing it and having to wait. Thanks!